# Creating an Approval workflow based on the list values using visual studio 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, visual-studio

I have a list with the company name, business process and workflow initiation.

The Business Process could be Purchase Order/ Leave Request.

Workflow Initiation is a radio button which could be

Manual, On creation or On change of List Column. I want to create an approval workflow for the list and based on what is entered in the list, I want the workflow to start functioning.

The following is the code which i have used

```
namespace wfmaintenance.Workflow1
{
    public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
    {
        public Workflow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Company;
        public string BusinessProcess;
        public string ListName;
        public string WorkflowName;
        public string WorkflowInitiation;  

        public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
        public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

        public SPWorkflowTaskProperties WfTaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
        public SPWorkflowTaskProperties WfTaskBeforeProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
        public Guid WfApproveTaskId = default(Guid);
        public int WfApproveTaskItemId;
        public bool WfApproveComplete = false;

        private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
        {
            /**  Company = workflowProperties.Item["Company"].ToString();
              BusinessProcess = workflowProperties.Item["BusinessProcess"].ToString();
              ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
              WorkflowName = workflowProperties.Item["WorkflowName"].ToString();
              WorkflowInitiation = workflowProperties.Item[" WorkflowInitiation"].ToString();
              checkApprovalStatus();
            **/
        }

        private void notWfTaskApproved(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Result = !WfApproveComplete;
        }



        private void createWfTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;

            // Set up some of the properties.
            WfApproveTaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
            WfTaskProperties.Title = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString() + " is ready for review";
            WfTaskProperties.Description = "Please review and ensure it is valid.  If it is valid, then please select 'Approved' on this task and save it.";

        }

        private void onWfTaskChanged_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
        {
            //int tid = onWfTaskChanged.AfterProperties.TaskItemId;
            SPListItem task = workflowProperties.Web.Lists["Workflow Tasks"] .GetItemById(WfApproveTaskItemId);

            SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;

    try
    {

        if (task["Business Approval"] != null)
        {
            // Evaluate the value of the field.
                if (task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Approved" || task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Rejected")

                    {
                        WfApproveComplete = true;
                        task[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
                        task["Status"] = "Completed";
                        task.Update();



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WfApproveComplete = false;

                    }
        }
        else
        {

            WfApproveComplete = false;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WfApproveComplete = false;

    }
}

        private void completeWfTask_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

     SPListItem task = workflowProperties.Web.Lists["Workflow Tasks"].GetItemById(WfApproveTaskItemId);

    //task[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
    //task["Status"] = "Completed";
    //task.SystemUpdate(false);


    SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;
    if (task["Business Approval"].ToString() == "Rejected")
    {
        string ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
        string currentTitle = workflowProperties.Item["Status"].ToString();
        workflowProperties.Item["Status"] = ListName + "is Rejected ";
        workflowProperties.Item.Update();
    }
    else
    {
        string ListName = workflowProperties.Item["ListName"].ToString();
        string currentTitle = workflowProperties.Item["Status"].ToString();
        workflowProperties.Item["Status"] =  "is Approved ";
        workflowProperties.Item.Update();
    }
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: are your approvers are entered from a peoplepicker column or a predefined spgroup- a group of spusers- within the site collection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this [link](http://realsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/custom-sequential-approval-workflow-via-visual-studio-2010/)

There a source code of [custom approval workflow](http://sequentialworkflow.codeplex.com/)
that you can change for your purpose.